# jQuery: set button visible if exist label.text

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button, label

```
Button 

<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add"/>

Label 

<asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Set button visible when the label1.text is different from ""

Comment: Does this happen when the page loads or can it happen at any time?

Comment: how is the button related to the label ? placement on the page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see you the label will get text during runtime unless it happens with jquery. So i will go with this approach:

Firstly add a style attribute to the label like so:

```
<asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:Label>
```

And then when the page loads do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{ 
  if ($("#label1").text() == "")
  { 
    $("#btnAdd").show();
  }
});
```

The question is very unclear though.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would probably be a starting point

```
$('label').each(function() {
   if ($(this).text() == '') {
      $(this).siblings('button').hide();
   }
});
```

How does the label related to the button ? im using [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) here so it would hide any buttons within the same parent